# How can i Save Data in CoreData an fill a dynamic TableView with it

Tags: ios, xcode

I have an Entity called "IT-Mentor" with the Attribute "name". I save several names like this

```
mentor.name = @"Hr. Rumel";
mentor.name = @"Hr. Schwarz";
```

It works, i tested it with NSLog

My problem is, how can i fill a dynamic Tableview with this Data?

The Cell of my TableView contains a Label. I can show the name "Hr. Rumel", it works fine, but if i try to show also "Hr. Schwarz" he overrides the name "Hr.Rumel". So my question is how to fill my dynamic tableView with this Data an show all names which are saved in CoreData.

Comment: We need more code: Show us the TableViewDelegate and Datasource methods, please.

Comment: Your question is very hard to answer. What does "but if i try to show also "Hr. Schwarz" he overrides the name "Hr.Rumel"" mean?

Comment: Oh yes, like Nick Weaver says :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you are just overwriting the property `name` in your managed object `mentor`. I think you need to create another managed object instance of IT-Mentor.

```
ITMentorClass* itMentor1 = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"IT-Mentor" inManagedObjectContext:theManagedObjectContext];
itMentor1.name = @"Hr. Rumel";
ITMentorClass* itMentor2 = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"IT-Mentor" inManagedObjectContext:theManagedObjectContext];
itMentor1.name = @"Hr. Schwarz";
```